# Force Javascript to convert stream into file returned from server

Tags: javascript, c#

I am making a call to server, which returns me a file (excel or pdf) but instead of downloading the file - it's failing. I just want to download the file when user clicks on the button. I tried following approaches,

**Approach 1:**
Added a button and then click event on it

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function () {
    var url = "www.getfile.com/GetFile.svc/files/?Id=" + GetID() + "Get&format=xlsx";
    $.getJSON(url)
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log("Failed");
    })
});
```

**Approach 2:**
Added a anchor tag and then changing it's href (which I need to to get some ID)

```
   $("#myAnchor").on("click", function () {
               var url = "www.getfile.com/GetFile.svc/files/?Id=" + GetID() + "Get&format=xlsx";
        this.href = url;
        return false;
    });
```

1st approach just shows "Failed" in console and 2nd approach does nothing at all..

[image]

I am getting data from the services and **IF I go to the web services URL in browser it just downloads the file**

My requirements are to download the file after clicking on it without any redirects involved.

Comment: approach 2 should work, only change this.href to window.location.href

Comment: @shakib thanks it worked !

Comment: you are welcome. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `this.href` to `window.location.href`, approach 2 should work. 
Here `this` refers to the click function context, what you want is to set the `window.location.href`

```
$("#myAnchor").on("click", function () {
    var url = "www.getfile.com/GetFile.svc/files/?Id=" + GetID() + "Get&format=xlsx";
    window.location.href = url;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not that complicated.

Create an iframe and hide it

```
<iframe id="FILE_DOWNLOAD_FRAME" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

When user clicks on a button just set frame src.

```
$("#myAnchor").on("click", function () {
    document.getElementById('FILE_DOWNLOAD_FRAME').src = "www.getfile.com/GetFile.svc/files/?Id=" + GetID() + "Get&format=xlsx";        
});
```

If you want this to work in IE8 for example you will have to check for browser version (there are tons of libraries about).

Or you can do it by adding a class to any element (html for example):

```
<!--IE8 HACK-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and then check it when setting frame source:

```
$("#myAnchor").on("click", function () {
    var frame = document.getElementById('FILE_DOWNLOAD_FRAME');
    if ($('html').is('.ie8'){
        frame.document.url = "www.getfile.com/GetFile.svc/files/?Id=" + GetID() + "Get&format=xlsx"
    }
    else {
        frame.src = "www.getfile.com/GetFile.svc/files/?Id=" + GetID() + "Get&format=xlsx";
    }   
});
```

I just copied your code, its up to you to make it prettier =)